# Laravel 5 Class 'Intervention\Image\ImageServiceProvider' not found

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

Hi I have problem with Intervention Image. When I use `composer update` or

```
php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Intervention\Image\ImageServiceProviderLaravel5"
```

I have error:

> [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException]
>     Class 'Intervention\Image\ImageServiceProvider' not found**

Have you idea? I did everything from http://image.intervention.io/getting_started/installation and I don't know what should I do now, please help me :)

Comment: Did you add the service provider before you installed the package ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Have you followed installation guide carefully ?

You need to first run:

```
composer require intervention/image
```

and you should modify `config.app.php` after you already install this package (so after `composer require`) and not before.

Comment: And make sure you have installed and enabled GD/Imagick extension.

Answer (score 2):

I solved by running

```
php artisan config:clear
```

than: 
`php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Intervention\Image\ImageServiceProviderLaravel5"`